# Storing JSON string to shopware store cookies

Tags: php, json, cookies, shopware

How is it possible to pass json string to cookie?
I have something like this in my Subscriber folder in shopware plugin:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
$this->setCookie($controller,json_encode($arr));
```

But it stores the following string:

```
%7B%22a%22%3A1%2C%22b%22%3A2%2C%22c%22%3A3%2C%22d%22%3A4%2C%22e%22%3A5%7D
```

I know that the problem is in php-json connection.

Comment: all whitespaces, equal signs and greater than signs have been encoded. have you tried decoding that string again with json_decode?

Comment: Yes,I`ve tried so. No sensible result was after decoding.